# Split date range into several specific date range chunks

Tags: c#, datetime, date-range

I have regular list of date ranges with specific value:

```
14.09.2012 - 31.12.2015 = 8.25
01.01.2016 - 13.06.2016 = 11.00
14.06.2016 - 18.09.2016 = 10.50
19.09.2016 - 26.03.2017 = 10.00
27.03.2017 - 01.05.2017 = 9.75
02.05.2017 - 18.06.2017 = 9.25
19.06.2017 - 17.09.2017 = 9.00
18.09.2017 - 29.10.2017 = 8.50
30.10.2017 - 17.12.2017 = 8.25
18.12.2017 - 11.02.2018 = 7.75
12.02.2018 - 25.03.2018 = 7.50
26.03.2018 - 16.09.2018 = 7.25
17.09.2018 - NOW = 7.50
```

I am looking for a method that divide one input data range into above data ranges taking into account coefficient value.

For example, if I have input date range **`01.01.2016`** - **`09.02.2016`**, I need to get one output date range and coefficient:

```
01.01.2016 - 13.06.2016 = 11.00
```

But if I have input date range **`01.01.2016 - 29.04.2017`**, I need to get following ranges and coefficients:

```
14.09.2012 - 31.12.2015 = 8.25 
01.01.2016 - 13.06.2016 = 11.00 
14.06.2016 - 18.09.2016 = 10.50 
19.09.2016 - 26.03.2017 = 10.00
27.03.2017 - 01.05.2017 = 9.75
```

Class for output data:

```
public class OutputItem 
{

    public OutputItem()
    {

    }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; } = new DateTime();

    public DateTime End { get; set; } = new DateTime();

    public double Coeff { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Method that I try to get output data

```
    private List<OutputItem> GetOutput(DateTime start, DateTime end, List<OutputItem> specificRanges)
    {
        List<OutputItem> periods = new List<OutputItem>();

        foreach (OutputItem sr in specificRanges)
        {
            if (start >= sr.Start && sr.End <= end)
            {
                periods.Add(new OutputItem { Start = sr.Start, End = sr.End, Coeff = sr.Coeff });
            }
        }

        return periods;
    }
```

Comment: I understand your first example where you only expect one output data range. But the second example is not clear. Should the input date range be 01.01.2016 - 29.04.2017 (2017 instead of 2016)?

Comment: You have an error From : start >= sr.Start To : start <= sr.Start.

Comment: Marius, you are right! The second example input date range is  01.01.2016 - 29.04.2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that in your second example the start date should have been before `01-01-2016` - because if I understand the question, you are looking to return all the ranges that overlap the start to end time you are passing to the method.
If that is indeed the case, you are close - but your condition is wrong.
The way to test if two ranges overlap is to check if one starts before the other ends and vice versa, as you can see in the wiki of the [overlap](/questions/tagged/overlap) tag:

> Two or more elements overlap when they partially or totally cover one another.
>   The way to find if the elements overlap or not is to test if one elements begins before the second one ends, while the second one begins before the first one ends.

So your method should be:

```
private List<OutputItem> GetOutput(DateTime start, DateTime end, List<OutputItem> specificRanges)
{
    List<OutputItem> periods = new List<OutputItem>();

    foreach (OutputItem sr in specificRanges)
    {
        if (start >= sr.End && sr.Start <= end)
        {
            periods.Add(new OutputItem { Start = sr.Start, End = sr.End, Coeff = sr.Coeff });
        }
    }

    return periods;
}
```