# divide date range into known number of equal chunks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I've seen [Split date range into date range chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690617/split-date-range-into-date-range-chunks)
and [Split date range into several specific date range chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020632/split-date-range-into-several-specific-date-range-chunks), that is not what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for simple function from momenjs, that will help me with known start date, end date and number of chunks (slices) to return an array of equal chunks.

07-15-20 start date
07-27-20 end date
I want to split it into 12 chunks

result = [07.15.20 00:00, 07.16.20 00:00, 07.17.20 00:00...]

Trouble starts when date is not so straightforward.

For ex. if I have start date as

```
    minTimeX = moment(sortedTests[0].date).format('x');
    maxTimeX = moment(sortedTests.length - 1].date).format('x');
```

and I want to divide this into equal 12 chunks and I cannot figure how I can calculate it manually. Is it implemented in momentjs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not sure if moment supports what you're looking for, but you can do it in javascript like this

```
function splitDateIntoEqualIntervals(startDate, endData, numberOfIntervals){

 let diff =  endData.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
 let intervalLength = diff/numberOfIntervals;
 let intervals = [];
 for(let i = 1 ; i <= numberOfIntervals;i++)
   intervals.push(new Date(startDate.getTime()+i*intervalLength))
 return intervals;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need chunks you probably need `start`, `end` and maybe `avg` of these chunks. So you can use this function similar to these proposed by @ibrachim

```
const splitDateIntoEqualIntervals = (startDate: Date, endDate: Date, numberOfIntervals: number):{start: Date, end: Date, avg: Date}[] => {
  const intervalLength = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / numberOfIntervals
  return [...(new Array(numberOfIntervals))]
    .map((e, i) => {
      return {
        start: new Date(startDate.getTime() + i * intervalLength),
        avg: new Date(startDate.getTime() + (i + 0.5) * intervalLength),
        end: new Date(startDate.getTime() + (i + 1) * intervalLength)
      }
    })
}
```

It returns array with chunks without arbitral of choice of start or end.

[image]